# Qmail: How to use custom hosts file?

Tags: qmail

For testing purposes, I am trying to send emails to `hello@test.com`, but qmail won't parse */etc/hosts*. It is running in a physical black box, so there is no way for it to access any DNS server.

How can I tell *qmail* to deliver emails going to `test.com` to a specific IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To relay outgoing mail for "example.com" to an SMTP server at 10.9.8.7 port 2500 with username "foo" and password "bar":

echo example.com:10.9.8.7:2500 foo bar >>/var/qmail/control/smtproutes
To relay all outgoing mail to an SMTP server at 10.9.8.7 port 25 with username "foo" and password "bar":

echo :10.9.8.7 foo bar >>/var/qmail/control/smtproutes

for more see http://tomclegg.net/qmail/